# setbackground issue in getview of listview

Tags: android

Based on the position , I need to change the background color of a textview in a listview.
only if the position is 1 I need to have the background color as red, else there should not be any background color.
Here is my getview, for the first position I'm getting the color as red, but for other positions, the background color is changing on scrolling the listview up and down

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                            R.layout.bookmarkslayout, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.bookMarkImage = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.bookMarkImage);
                    holder.bookMarkTitle = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.bookMarkTitle);
                    holder.bookMarksLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.bookMarksLayout);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                if (getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    holder.bookMarksLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                } else {
                    holder.bookMarksLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                }
                holder.bookMarkImage.setBackgroundResource(getResources()
                        .getIdentifier(albumArray[position], "drawable",
                                "com.cognizant.vivid"));
                // holder.bookMarkTitle.setText(albumArray[position]);
                holder.bookMarkTitle.setText(AccountsArray[position]);
                if (AccountsArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Add Account")) {
                    holder.bookMarkTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }else{
                    holder.bookMarkTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#40808080"));
                }
                holder.bookMarksLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // player.reset();
                        if (position == 0) {
                            player.stop();
                            player.release();
                            player = null;
                            surfaceholder = surfaceView.getHolder();
                            surfaceholder.addCallback(Player.this);
                            surfaceholder
                                    .setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
                            player = new MediaPlayer();
                            player.setDisplay(surfaceholder);
                            player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
                            try {
                                player.setDataSource(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        Uri.parse("http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/uds/pd/1937897674001/1937897674001_1939672863001_Wildlife-TamarinMonkey.mp4"));
    //                          player.setDataSource(
    //                                  getApplicationContext(),
    //                                  Uri.parse("http://mspss.cognizant.com/vivid/videos/intuit/2intuit.mp4"));
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                            player.setOnPreparedListener(Player.this);
                            player.prepareAsync();
                            // player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                            player.setOnCompletionListener(Player.this);
                            secondaryBookMarksAdapter adapter = new secondaryBookMarksAdapter();
                            bookMarkListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            bookMarkListViewLandscape.setAdapter(adapter);
                            // VideoTimerHandler videoTimerHandler = new
                            // VideoTimerHandler();
                            // videoTimerHandler.playVideoTimer();
                            // playVideo("http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/uds/pd/1937897674001/1937897674001_1939672863001_Wildlife-TamarinMonkey.mp4");
                        } else {
                            if (position == 1) {
                                player.seekTo(115000);
                                timeline.setProgress(115000);
                                player.seekTo(30000);
                                timeline.setProgress(30000);
                            }
                            if (position == 2) {
                                player.seekTo(140000);
                                timeline.setProgress(140000);
                            }
                            if (position == 3) {
                                player.seekTo(205000);
                                timeline.setProgress(205000);
                            }
                            if (position == 4) {
                                player.seekTo(270000);
                                timeline.setProgress(270000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setting it to RED if there is a match and else you set it to something else:

```
        if (AccountsArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Add Account")) {
            holder.bookMarkTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
            holder.bookMarkTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#40808080"));
        }
```

My guess is that you have multiple "Add Account" matches. Please try to set a breakpoint inside else.

Comment: here is the array private String[] AccountsArray = { "Add Account", "Charts of Accounts",
   "Features Selected", "Company File Location", "QB Set Up" };

Comment: @user2558496 did you try setting a breakpoint and see if it was reaching RED multiple times?